# Syntax for looping formula through cells error

Tags: vba, excel

When I run this code I get an "Application-defined or object-defined error" and I have no clue how to fix my code. I am new to VBA and macros. Below is my code. I am trying to go cell by cell by comparing a value to another list and then moving one row down.

```
For i = 1 To 133
    For k = 1 To 133
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Cells(i + 1, 2),Sheet2!R[k+1]C[3])),Sheet2!R[k+1]C[5],"""")" 
    Next k  
Next i
```

Comment: since the target cell is not changing on the inner loop you are putting replacing the formula 133 time in the same cell.  This is not your problem, but raises another question.

Comment: What formula are you trying to put in the first cell?  And, what should it change to in the next cell.

Comment: I want to compare the value in the target cell to a list.

Comment: What exactly is the formula you want in the first and second cell, then we can help you translate that into a workable vba.

Comment: So I am trying to compare if the value left of the first cell is found in another set of data and if found, I want the first cell to be filled with data from another column but same row as the cell that has the matching data. I am trying to find a way to quickly do this and thought a macro was best.

Comment: yes but if you do not have a working formula in the first place trying to insert a non working formula will not work.  Right now if you got the formula working it would enter `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,Sheet2!C134)),Sheet2!E134,"")` in the first cell and `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A3,Sheet2!C134)),Sheet2!E134,"")` in the second.  it will always end up with the last row in the cell.  I don't think this is what you want.  Please show some test data and expected output.

Comment: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,C1)),D1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,C2)),D2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,C3)),D3,"")))      I am not sure how to format this but essentially this is the formula but as a shorthand and I tested it in excel and it worked.

Comment: You have another problem you are putting the formula in the same cell you are referencing in the formula, you cannot do that.

Comment: That is not what I am trying to do. Also, if my code doesn't work as expected I will adjust, but I can't even get through a run so I have no idea what to expect and change.

Comment: You have to remove the vba parts from the string and concatenate like Tim showed you.  And I commented how to make the reference R1C1.  Did you replace the part in Tim's code with my commented code fix?

Comment: Yes I did, so now it runs.

Comment: Also by your formula in your comment use this formula: `=VLOOKUP("*" & A2 & "*",Sheet2!C:E,3,FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
For i = 1 To 133

    For k = 1 To 133
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = _
           "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & Cells(i + 1, 2).Address(False, False, xlR1C1) & _
           ",Sheet2!R[" & (k+1) & "]C[3])),Sheet2!R[" & (k+1) & "]C[5],"""")"

    Next k  

Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately the same error still occurs.

Comment: If you enter the formula manually does it work?  Try using `Debug.Print` to view the generated formula, then copy/paste it into a cell and see what error you get.

Comment: @TimWilliams you are mixing A1 and R1C1 styles.  But I doubt the final outcome is what the OP wants, but it will fix the error if you use: `Cells(i + 1, 2).Address(0,0,xlR1C1)`

Comment: If I don't need the R1C1 and can just use Formula that would be fine, I am not sure which is better to use.

Comment: @ScottCraner - thanks for the catch.  I almost never use R1C1 approach...